# scrolling two listview and handle click event

Tags: android, listview, scroll, onclicklistener

I'm scrolling two listview by passing touch event to both of them.

```
 OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
                    boolean dispatched = false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if (v.equals(m_lv1) && !dispatched) {
                                    m_listAdapter1.setEnabled(true);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                    m_listAdapter2.setEnabled(false);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                    dispatched = true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                    m_lv2.dispatchTouchEvent(event);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                            } else if (v.equals(m_lv2) && !dispatched) {
                                    m_listAdapter1.setEnabled(false);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                    m_listAdapter2.setEnabled(true);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                    dispatched = true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                    m_lv1.dispatchTouchEvent(event);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                            }
                            dispatched = false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                    }
            };
```

which works fine.

I also have OnItemClickListener for both of list views and it works fine as well

```
     m_lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
..
}
});
```

Now I add clickListener to sub-layout of the cells of list views.

```
        if(viewHolder.layout_author != null) {
            viewHolder.layout_author.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(ImageListAdapter.this.activity, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("JsonUser", jsonAlbumImage.jsonUser);
                        ImageListAdapter.this.activity.startActivity(profileIntent);
                    }
                });
        }
```

Then, I find scrolling doesn't work sometimes.
I guess its because the new clickListener is consuming the touch events.

Any suggestion/guide is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
You should implement interface OnItemClickListener and then use its Overrided method
```

onItemClick. set your listViews onItemClickListeners. Now in the Overrided Method "onItemClick" compare its parameter "parent" with your listViews.
    e.g:

```
if (parent.equals(listView1)) {
    /* your code here */
} else if(parent.equals(listView2){
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: thanks for input. But I can actually handle OnItemClickListener. I want different action for click on the subview of the cell.